# How to speed up for-loop or use an alternative method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

Any way I can speed up this for-loop or use an alternative method? I was thinking of doing some sort of map or list comprehension.

```
Query = [5,7,9,10,12,13,14,16]
Top = range(1,30)
X = range(5,17)
Limit = range(1,20)


Results = []

#Test1 is a function
for Q in tqdm(Query):
    for t in Top:
        for x1 in X:
            for l in Limit:
                df1 = Test1(df = pred2,Results = QBResults,Query = Q ,Top = t, X = x1, Limit = l)
                df2 = Test1(df = TestDF,Results = QBResults,Query = Q ,Top = t, X = x1, Limit = l)
                df1['Query'] = Q
                df1['Top'] = t
                df1['X'] = x1
                df1['Limit'] = l
                df1['Df1AggScore'] = df1['AggScore']
                df1['Df2AggScore'] = df2['AggScore']
                df1['Df1TopScore'] = df1['TopScore']
                df1['Df2TopScore'] = df2['TopScore']
                df1['Diff'] = np.abs(df1['Df1AggScore'] - df1['Df2AggScore'])
                df1['Diff'] = np.abs(df1['Df1TopScore'] - df1['Df2TopScore'])
                Results.append(df1)
Opt = pd.concat(Results)
Opt.sort_values(by='Df2TopScore', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Please follow python naming convention, variable should start lowercase ;)

Comment: This question does better fit to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stovfl when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the title would need to be updated to describe what the code does instead of the OPs goals for change.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools` module has a function, `product`, that returns a cartesian product generator. With this function, your code can be refactored from using four `for` loops to using one.

```py
from itertools import product
for Q, t, x1, l in product(tqdm(Query), Top, X, Limit):
    ...
```